# DB2 SQL: Replicate the IF-ELSE Statement from EXCEL and using CASE statement from DB2 SQL

Tags: excel, db2

I'm trying to replicate the IF-ELSE statement from Excel using DB2 SQL using the CASE statement. My data has 4 dates per line and it could be any date in the calendar year. In Excel the formula works perfectly, however, I having problems getting the CASE statement to correctly get the answer.

Do anyone has any ideas if it is correctly coded or if I have other alternatives to accomplish the same result using DB2 SQL?

From example: My question if **My Date is within Beg or End Dates?**

**Condition**:
                 Beginning Date: 1/1/2010   E2
                    Ending Date: 12/31/2018 E3
                        My Date: 8/22/2018  E4
    Ending Date if Blank r Null: 1/1/1900   E5
                         Answer: 1    Logic if True = 1 ; Not = 0
           **Excel Formula**: 
           IF(E3<>E5,IF(E3<=E4,0,IF(E2>E4,0,1)),IF(E2>E4,0,1))

**DB2 SQL CODE**:

```
(CASE WHEN E3  <> E5    
      THEN (CASE WHEN E3 <= E4  
                 THEN '0'   
                 ELSE (CASE WHEN E2 > E4    
                            THEN '0'    
                            ELSE '1' END)  END) 
      ELSE (CASE WHEN E2 > E4   
                 THEN '0'   
                 ELSE '1' END)  END)
```

Comment: Logic seems fine to me, however I do not see any NULL checks in the DB2 code, like WHEN IFNULL(E3,'1900-01-01)  <>   IFNULL(E5,'1900-01-01)

Comment: Can you please format your Condition so that it's possible to tell which cell is which value?  I'm not sure if E2 is "Beginning Date: 1/1/2010" or "Ending Date: 12/31/2018"

Answer (score 0):

Have you stored your dates as `DATE` datatype? If you have stored them as strings, then your comparisons will just be alphabetic and e.g. `"8/22/2018"` will be greater than "`12/31/2018`" as 8 comes after 1 in the character set.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "if Blank r Null" , but you can use COALESCE to cast an `NULL` marker to the value you want to use in your comparison.

You can also simplify the `CASE` statement. E.g. see the 2nd result column below

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN E3  <> E5    
      THEN (CASE WHEN E3 <= E4
                 THEN '0'   
                 ELSE (CASE WHEN E2 > E4    
                            THEN '0'    
                            ELSE '1' END)  END) 
      ELSE (CASE WHEN E2 > E4   
                 THEN '0'   
                 ELSE '1' END)  END) AS RESULT
,   CASE WHEN E2 > E4 OR ( E3  <> E5 AND E3 <= E4) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       AS SIMPLER
FROM 
TABLE(VALUES (DATE('2010-1-1'), DATE('2018-12-31'),DATE('2018-8-22'), DATE('1900-1-1'))
                ) AS V(E2,E3,E4,E5)
```